# is using an exception to return from deep recursion legit?

Tags: java, exception, recursion

I had a test in OOP methodology and was asked the following True\False question:

> "Throwing an exception in order to return from a deep recursive call is considered a legitimate use of the exceptions mechanism".

I thinks it's false because it's not really an exception in the application's flow, but my teacher marked it as true, saying it's a quick way of returning from deep recursions.

In my opinion it's analogues to wrapping a for block with try\catch when dealing with an IndexOutofBounds, which isn't correct coding.

Which is right in your opinion?

Answer (score 6):

Using exceptions to *return* from recursion is *wrong*. Exceptions are for exceptional situations. Returning from recursion is not an exceptional situation.

From the Java language tutorials:

> The Java programming language uses exceptions to **handle errors and other exceptional events**.

and

> An exception is an event that occurs during the execution of a program that **disrupts the normal flow of instructions**.

It *is* wrong, and against standard programming practice because programmers expect exceptions to be used for **exceptional situations**. Any other use is *wrong*. Period.

Comment: Well, if you are recursing 10.000 times, then returning *is* actually exceptional, isn't it? And, yes, it disrupts the normal flow of instructions.

Comment: @Ingo Returning is *not* exceptional.

Comment: Plus there are serious WTF momements when you put a `catch (Exception e)...` somewhere in the stack for unrelated reasons and suddenly your function doesn't return properly.

Comment: @jozefg This is one reason why `catch (Exception x)` is frowned upon.

Comment: @johnchen902 So, how is "some file does not exist" an exception? An exception is that what the programmer/designer **thinks** is exceptional.

Comment: @Ingo If you thinks its not exceptional, you should check `File.exists` first.

Comment: To be sure, it is against standard programming practices, no doubt. But that was not the question.

Comment: @Jason: You should mention a quick overview of *correct* ways to return from deep recursions.

Comment: @hexafraction: Disconnect the power source. :-)

Comment: Question probably belongs on Programmers.  Check [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/161488/44767).

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, if trying to keep a code clear, using exceptions should be reserved to handling errors.

However, the use of exceptions to return from a deep recursion was long used by Caml programmers to be able to finish a recursion without having to unstack all the calls (losing time for nothing).

But now, the recursion mechanisms (at least in Caml) introduced in-place recursion. This means that when calling a recursive function, if it is terminal (no computations after the call), then the stack frame will be replaced instead of being added. This implies that it is no longer necessary to unstack all the calls, nor to avoid doing this using an exception.

So to my mind, exceptions should only be used to prevent errors, since their other usage is now out-of-date (at least in some languages).

Answer (score -2):

It is absolutly legitimate by the rules of Java and the JVM, and the semantics are clear. Yet, as it is about control flow, it has almost nothing to do with OOP. The same feature could be used in a language that is not OO, but happens to have exceptions.

The crucial point here is the word *legitimate*: If we say that everything that is not forbidden nor does not exploit undefined features is legitimate, then sure, jumping through exceptions is legitimate.

That doesn't mean: it is *good practice*. But then .... *good practice* is that, what the majority of Java programmers understands, and this is not too much, IMHO ....

Only one thing: Use a pre-fabricated user-defined-exception if you need to do that often, because creating exception objects in Java is expensive due to stack trace collection.

Comment: *Exception* should only be used with something *exceptional*.

Comment: @johnchen902 Well, you know, throwing/catching exceptions has a very well defined semantics in Java. There may be good reasons to do a "long jump" from a recursing function. Sure, it is not something that occurs in day to day programming.

Comment: Exception is not a long-jump. JVM will only **retreat**, **frame by frame**.

Comment: @johnchen902 I know, iand it will run finally blocks all the way up. That's why I put "long jump" in quotation marks.

Comment: It's not me who down-voted. But, of course OP is asking if it is a good practice, not if it is really legitimate.

Comment: @johnchen902 Last time I checked the question was if it is legit.

Comment: I meant, don't literalism. (For example, don't argue that use literalism as a verb, I just translated 拘泥於字句 by Google.)